# The connection file changes when I run the program

Tags: wpf

file myProject.exe.config changed to another project connection string when I run project. (if rebuild project myProject.exe.config create Properly)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i run my project in bin\debug, file myprojectname.exe.config change wrong

Comment: file2.exe.config =  "Test2Entity" when run project file2.exe.config change to "Test1Entity"